# mxDestroyArray double free or corruption

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I am running Matlab from a Fortran function and am having a persistent problem that I am getting the error

```
*** glibc detected *** /matlab/8.5/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: double free or corruption (out): 0x00002b11a9a86f20 ***
```

I am not sure which line the error is occuring on but I have quite a few that follow this pattern

```
MLVar = engGetVariable(ep, 'un')
call mxCopyPtrToReal8(mxGetPr(MLVar), SurfaceField, BoundaryCells)
call mxDestroyArray(MLVar)
```

and I go through this function between 1 and 100s of times before this error occurs.

It looks like [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/256991) they said to use `mxDestroyArray` which I'm already using.

Any advise?

Comment: Just a complete guess: maybe you should enclose the calls to `mxCopyPtrToReal8()` and `mxDestroyArray()` into a `if ( MLVar != 0 ) then ` `endif` block...

Comment: How is MLVar created?

Comment: MLVar is declared as `mwPointer MLVar`

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being completely unrelated. I am submitting this to a remote cluster using a submission script, and I used a "V" option and then when I closed my terminal connection with Matlab forced close.